# I can't save data to database with Django and SQL Anywhere 11

Tags: django, python-2.7, connection, database-connection, sqlanywhere

I have connected django with sql anywhere 11 database, I have follow the instructions on the page [SQL Anywhere Django Driver](https://github.com/sqlanywhere/sqlany-django) from github.

I have created the database with this command:

```
C:\>dbinit -z UCA django.db --> (database created successful)
```

I have started the Database Server with command:

```
C:\>dbsrv11 django.db  --> (database server started successful)
```

I have created my project with:

```
C:\>django-admin.py startproject mysite (at this point all it's ok)
```

I have edited the file mysite/mysite/settings.py and I have changed the DATABASES setting with this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sqlany_django',
        'NAME': 'django',
        'USER': 'dba',
        'PASSWORD': 'sql',
        'OPTIONS': {'eng': 'django'}
    }
}
```

When I want to sync database using this command:

```
c:/mysite>python manage.py syncdb
```

the prompt show me a error message (the error message is shown below)

I have connected Sybase Central to `django.db` I see the tables was created.
but when I try save data to the tables this data wasn't recorded
even when I have created the superuser with this command:

```
c:\mysite>python manage.py createsuperuser --username=joe --email=joe@example.com
Password:123
Password (again):123
Superuser created successfully.
```

I querying the datebase with:

```
select * from auth_user
```

No rows are shown
The data aren't saved

I have an environment for test with this features:

```
O.S.: Windows XP   
DB Engine: SQL Anywhere 11 with EBF 3069 
Python 2.7
Django 1.6.1 
Setuptools installed 
PIP installed 
sqlanydb installed
sqlany-django installed
```

Here is the **error message**

```
C:\mysite>python manage.py syncdb
Creating tables ...
Creating table django_admin_log
Creating table auth_permission
Creating table auth_group_permissions
Creating table auth_group
Creating table auth_user_groups
Creating table auth_user_user_permissions
Creating table auth_user
Creating table django_content_type
Creating table django_session
Creating table Personal_persona
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 242,
 in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 285,
 in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 415,
 in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\syncdb.py"
, line 112, in handle_noargs
    emit_post_sync_signal(created_models, verbosity, interactive, db)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\sql.py", line 216,
in emit_post_sync_signal
    interactive=interactive, db=db)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 185,
in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\__init__.py
", line 101, in create_permissions
    auth_app.Permission.objects.using(db).bulk_create(perms)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 356, in b
ulk_create
    self._batched_insert(objs_without_pk, fields, batch_size)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 835, in _
batched_insert
    using=self.db)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 232, in
 _insert
    return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1511, in
insert_query
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 90
3, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\util.py", line 69, in e
xecute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\util.py", line 53, in e
xecute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 99, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\util.py", line 53, in e
xecute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlany_django\base.py", line 87, in execut
e
    ret = self.cursor.execute(trace(query), trace(args))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlanydb.py", line 714, in execute
    self.executemany(operation, [parameters])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlanydb.py", line 685, in executemany
    bind_count = self.api.sqlany_num_params(self.stmt)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlanydb.py", line 619, in __stmt_get
    self.handleerror(*self.parent.error())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlanydb.py", line 613, in handleerror
    eh(self.parent, self, errorclass, errorvalue)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlanydb.py", line 342, in standardErrorHa
ndler
    raise errorclass(errorvalue)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: Syntax error near ',' on line 1
```

Comment: Did you notice the first step: Install SQL Anywhere 12.0.1 (or higher)? The SQL Anywhere Django driver has never been tried with SQL Anywhere version 11.

Comment: Yes, but my company's database engine is SQl Anywhere 11 and I need urgently develop application with django. What solution do you suggest me, related to Django and SQL Anywhere 11

Comment: @GraemePerrow will this work with the SAP IQ Client 16?

Comment: @toasteez I doubt it's ever been tried with IQ but I don't know of any reason why it wouldn't work with v16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but the SQL Anywhere Django driver requires SQL Anywhere v12 or higher; you cannot use it with SQL Anywhere v11. I have confirmed that the driver uses features of the database server that were not supported in version 11.

*Disclaimer: I work for SAP in SQL Anywhere engineering.*

Comment: Ok Graeme, thanks for your time and your help, but I hope SQL Anywhere Django driver support old SQL Anywhere 11 in next versions.